# improving syntax in writing functions - multiple default arguments

Tags: r, function

This may be a silly question, I am trying to improve my function writing skills. Let's say I have the following function:

```
my_fx<- function(my_argument1, my_argument2=c('option1', 'option2')) {
 input_arg<- match.arg(my_argument2)
 if(input_arg=='option1') {
    #feed my_argument1 to internal_function_1
 } else #feed my_argument1 to internal_function_2}
```

I am using `match.arg` to get a clear error message in case the input does not match allowed arguments, bu I wonder if there is a more direct way to call the right subfunction rather than the if/else statement. Looking forward to receiving your feedback :)

Comment: You could use a `switch` statement.

Comment: Perfect, I have just tested it and it works great! Thank you :)